# Is it necessary to specify Spring JstlView resolver to use JSTL in JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

While using `InternalResourceViewResolver` in Spring, is it necessary to specify `viewClass` as 
`org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView` to use JSTL? Because without specifying it I am still able to access JSTL tags (I used `<c:out/>`) in JSP without any exception or error.

Comment: FYI: JSTL is not part of Spring. It's part of Java EE / JSP. So the implication that some Spring specific class is required in order to use JSTL is truly weird.

Comment: Yes, but my question is why it is necessary although I am able to use JSTL without specifying it

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini  It is not necessary, it has been written in 2003 to enable support for jstl, but now with the latest versions of spring you don't need to specify it as it will automaticaly detect

Comment: Yes I also think so . It will be auto detected while jstl jar is in classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at seeing the
[InternalResourceViewResolver](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web.servlet/3.2.3/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.java#InternalResourceViewResolver) and [here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/trunk/src/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.java?p=14417)

The JstlView class is set by default if  we resolve view using InternalResourceViewResolver and jstl jar is in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't know about jstl as it is not part of Spring, this will work as bridge to JSTL
View name returned from a handler will be translated to a JSP resource (for example: "myView" -> "/WEB-INF/jsp/myView.jsp"), using this view class to enable **explicit JSTL support**.

It will also  exposes JSTL-specific request attributes specifying locale and resource bundle for JSTL's formatting and message tags, using Spring's locale and MessageSource.

When you are loading your properties from resource file (.properties file)

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
 </bean>
```

The specified MessageSource loads messages from "messages.properties" etc files in the class path. This will automatically be exposed to views as JSTL localization context, which the JSTL fmt tags (message etc) will use.

Source : [JSTL View](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html)

Comment: please add more clarification of second paragraph

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini clarification about what ? clarified in the below example it self. Let me know if you have any concerns

Answer (score 0):

**Because without specifying it I am still able to access JSTL tags:**

-> This is because InternalResourceViewResolver, internally checks (during instantiation inside constructor) whether JSTL classes (specifically javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config) present in class path and spring class loader can load it successfully.
So, if class is present and can be loaded, it will automatically use JstlView over InternalResourceView. And all this happens inside it's default constructor only.

So, you do not specifically need to tell to use JstlView. It will be taken automatically.
In your case, it JSTL config class available in classpath so, it's working.